# How do I batch rename image files already on the server?

Tags: batch-processing, file-rename

I have hundreds of images on my server (Linux-based shared hosting) already. I want to rename these files at once using batch processing. The names are some gibberish, and what I want them named as is "mysitecom_image_001.jpg", "mysitecom_image_002.jpg", etc.

Can this be done in cPanel or FTP?

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Any help?